# capacitive switch behind a mirror (silver backing)

Tags: touchscreen, capacitive, inductive, metal, mirror

I am new to this field, and I would like to DIY a mirror with a hidden capacitive \inductive touch sensor behind it, once touched it will turn on a 12V LED light.

I have bought a capacitive switch but it does not work behind a mirror. After doing some research I think it has to do with the silver backing of the mirror (interfere with the magnetic field perhaps ? ).

Can you please recommend me on what technology should I be looking in (capacitive, inductive, piezo) in order to achieve my goal ?
btw, this is a regular commercial bathroom mirror.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SE. Add a link to the datasheet for the switch.

Comment: If you can use conductive paint to make contact with the silver backing, you may be able to use the mirror itself as a capacitive switch sensor.

Comment: Thanks for replying guys. transistor, link [link](http://tinyurl.com/gqfjmjx). No datasheet Im afraid. Brian, I tried putting foil between and it didnt do the trick. Also, what your suggesting would theoretically make the entire mirror one large touch sensor no ?

Comment: Are you able to etch the silvering to break the the backing into separate conductors. Then you could have multiple touch areas. Does the mirror aesthetic permit that?

Comment: Hi Neil, I guess I can sandblast the borders of the place, thus removing the silvering and paint. Would the switch in the link (capacitive touch) suffice or would this :[link](http://tinyurl.com/zkwl7or) (conductive touch) do the trick ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

A mirror typically has a metal coating, protected on one side by glass and on the other by paint.   That will complicate any electrical sensing of a finger.   You might have better luck using a temperature sensor, and having a spot on the mirror sensitive to a warm finger.   Two biased diodes or transistors (base-collector shorted together to make a diode) and a difference sensing amplifier can do the
trick.   On very hot days, you'll have to press your finger to the cold-side
transistor's location, though.

Comment: Hi Whit3rd, if what your saying is true, how can this thing work [link](http://tinyurl.com/zfrerzu)? From what I understand, those are touch capacitive sensors of some type otherwise they wouldnt perform well in a bathroom. Thanks

Comment: The image looks like there's an etched pattern in the reflective layer.   The sensor is visible, not hidden.

Comment: So the etched border should suffice? The inside contact will still have silvering in it. Thanks

Comment: Still no go after etching a pattern (borders) in the mirror. Any ideas? Anyone? Thanks

Comment: If you've etched away the aluminum, through-glass  capacitive sensing techniques should work; one might use a cotton swab with lye solution to be sure the  last of the Al metallization is gone.  Clean carefully, and apply fingernail polish to seal around the paint edges.

Answer (score 0):

you will need a non conductive mirror glass for the touch sensor to operate if it is a capactive touch sensor/switch.

Schott makes a glass for these applications. See link below, BTW it is not cheap.
http://www.schott.com/architecture/english/products/decorative-glass/mirona.html